# Open "Screen Sharing" tab in System Preferences > Privacy using terminal

Tags: terminal, security, screen-sharing

I have been searching for a way to open System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Screen Sharing using a script. I'm a systems admin and I'm trying to deploy TeamViewer to my users in the easiest way possible, but PPPC creates an obstacle; I can't remotely enable Screen Sharing and I want my users to click as few times as possible.

So far I have this:
`open "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy"`

I'm so far unable to find the correct ID for Screen Sharing. If I insert 
`...?Privacy_Photos"` or any other number of options, it works, but I cannot find the ID for screen sharing. Is there an ID for this? Or is there a better way to do this? How is TeamViewer able to do this using their GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Found it! it's `Privacy_ScreenCapture`

`open "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ScreenCapture"`

I found it by going to /System/Library/PreferencePanes showing contents on security and then looking at the PrivacyServicesOrder.plist